# How can I save form's value into mysql database table? (post method)

Tags: python, mysql, database, django, post

```
mysql> describe posts;
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id       | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| title    | varchar(300)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| content  | varchar(1000) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| created  | date          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| modified | date          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

How would i create form in template? How would i access the value of that form in views.py and save into database table? I have also read this=> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/ but could not understand how to implement it.

Comment: 1. What has this got to do with MySQL? Why is the SQL table structure relevant? 2. This is fully covered in the documentation.

Comment: Which documentation? django book or django official documentation?

Comment: It's covered in both the [official](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) and the django book that jcollado linked to below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chapter 7 in the [django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07/) addresses your question.

Comment: +1 for Django Book. I think this is really basic situation and it is worth to learn it now to save the time later :)